# Ignore spatial mapping with gaze controls

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a virtual model that is buried under sand, which results in the spatial mapping being above the model. However I want to have the gaze control on the model and not on the spatial mapping so that I can interact with my model directly. How can this be archived?

Comment: Not sure about newer versions, but if using the MRTK the GazeManager allowed you to specify a sequence of layer masks to use in priority order.  Set your model to its own layer and put that as the first entry.  Then add a second entry with a later mask including the SpatialMapping layer.  The gaze will look for your model first, and if not found it will then look for the spatial mapping.  If this MRTK solution isn't an option, then you could do similar using Raycast.

Comment: I can't find the sequence for the layermask, but I think I figured out how to do it with a custom cursor and raycasting to specific layers. I'll update once everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting too much time on a custom cursor that never really worked I found out how to do it the right way (Thanks @Jethro !).

First create a special layer for all holograms that should get the GazeControll first. This is under `Edit -> Project Settings -> Tags and Layers`. Assign all special holograms to this layer.

On the `InputManager` is a script called `GazeManager`. On this script there is a field called `Raycast Layer Masks`. Set the size to 2 and below that `Element 0` and `Element 1` appear. Set `Element 0` to the special layer created and `Element 1` to all other layers and you got it.